# ClosedXMLで別ブックにシートをコピーする際に値のみでコピーしたい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

ClosedXMLでExcel1(book1.xlsx)のワークシートをExcel2(book2.xlsx)にコピーする処理を実装中です。

```
var copySheet = excel1._Workbook.WorkSheet(1);
copySheet.CopyTo(excel2._Workbook, sheetName, nSheetNum);
excel2._Workbook.Save();
```

book1.xlsxにはセル参照等が入っており、上記のように行うとセル参照も一緒にコピーされてしまうため、値のみコピーしたいのですが、なにか方法はありますか？

宜しくお願い致します。

visual studio 2017 / C#